# Shadowing a parameter. Why is this allowed?

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, reference

A colleague brought some code to my attention.  I'm not sure if it was done intentionally or on accident, but it seems to me to be very bad practice.  Is there any circumstance when doing this would be a good idea? and what is happening under the hood that allows it to happen?  is this essentially overloading of an object?

A function examines a input class by reference for a validity bit, and if it is not found, allocates memory for a new object with the same name shadowing the original parameter.

```
class C
{
    public:
    bool valid = false;
};

void func(C &c)
{
    if(!c.valid)
    {
        C  * c = new C;
    
        if(c)
        {
          delete c;
          c = 0;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: It's usually not a great idea, but C++ isn't known for how well it protects its users from themselves.

Comment: There is nothing unusual happening under the hood. It's exactly the same as if you had `C * d = new D;`, except that the function argument `c` can't be referred to in this case. Identifiers are not necessarily unique, multiple objects can have the same identifier provided the context is different.

Comment: So on one hand it's similar to the concept of overloading, except you would no longer be able to access the reference parameter?

Comment: This is different from overloading. Overloading a function defines a new function with the same identifier, and both the old and new functions are accessible. With shadowing, the shadowed identifier is usually no longer reachable at all. Shadowing does not really have anything useful to offer, it is mostly a result of the language rules and not a feature that was willingly implemented.

Comment: Sometimes you want this behaviour. Sometimes you don't. The compiler's not qualified to figure out what the silly human at the keyboard really wants, so until we get telepathy support in some future Standard revision we're stuck. Some static analysis tools will highlight this as a point of interest.

Comment: FWIW, the lesson was learned in C#.  Shadowing a variable is a hard error there.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it is a pointer.  The second if is just a standard check to make sure the pointer hasn’t already been deleted.  It’s boilerplate, I think delete may make the same check, but I’ve just gotten used to doing it that way.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you are correct.  I didn’t catch that before.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any circumstance when doing this would be a good idea?

Not really. `gcc` with `-Wshadow -Werror` will trigger an error (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/esE18f)).

> and what is happening under the hood that allows it to happen?

`C * c = new C;` declares `c` to be a pointer to a newly created `C`. Your code leaks that memory, but is otherwise "not wrong".

> is this essentially overloading of an object?

No. It is called "shadowing". `c` is declared inside the scope `{/*...*/}` and inside that scope you cannot access the `c` from the outer scope, because it is shadowed.